# Google Apps - many of the emails sent from the server are going into people's spam boxes

Tags: google-apps, dkim

We have bought the  google apps account for the domain www.amarramesh.com hosted by bluehost.com

As per the google apps suggestion, we altered the CNAME records in bluehost for the domain www.amarramesh.com to sync with google apps.

There is an issue when I send the mail through a PHP  file stored in my Bluehost server. I tested the email quality through mail-tester.com and it says the DKIM signature is not valid because in the DKIM signature selector = "default" and suggests I should change to "google.domainkey".  Due to this, many of the emails sent from the server are going into people's spam boxes. How do I make this change? This problem doesn't happen when email is sent from Gmail.

I have tried Php-mailer and it worked for some time but Bluehost has now blocked it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send mail from another host if you're using GoogleApps?

DKIM's purpose is to allow remote hosts to authenticate that your mail was *really* sent by the server(s) you permit to send them. This prevents a spammer from forging your domain name on spam he is sending out. If it wasn't bounced off of servers you authorized in your DKIM DNS record, remote mail servers won't deliver it -- or maybe send it to the spam folder (provided they look at the DKIM header and DNS record).

It does this by putting a private key encrypted header on the mail, and the public key to decrypt it on the DNS record. If it can be decrypted successfully, then it is assumed to be legit (because the sender knew the private key).

This might help if you want to enable mail being sent from both hosts.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tzink/2013/04/26/how-to-set-up-your-dkim-records-if-you-are-outsourcing-some-or-all-of-your-email/

Comment: Failing that, removing the DKIM record would work too, with the inherent risks. I wouldn't try this unless you really were desperate for a short term fix.

Comment: Hai joe.Thanks for you response.My direct Question How to change the DKIM selector from "default" to "google.doaminkey"

Comment: You should see that in your DNS record with the key. I believe at the beginning. Instead of 

default._domainkey.myexampledomain.com

Google has a generator to help you with keys for their domain

https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en

Comment: This is the Exact problem Iam having...There is no problem If I use the SMTP...The issue is when I send the mail through my bluehost.                If you use an outbound mail gateway that modifies outgoing messages, such as adding a compliance footer, the change invalidates the DKIM signature. You need to prevent the gateway server from modifying messages or have the gateway server subsequently DKIM sign the messages.